# Create dynamic header in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a header , whose contents update from mysql itself . I have two tables

1. courses_names having cid and cname having fileds maths , physics, chemisry , computers
2. items having id , name , course id having fields trigo , 3d , algebra , vectors, mechanics, thermodynamics,avagadro , c++

Course_id is same as cid in courses_names table

i have used this sql command

```
 $q="SELECT id,name,cname
FROM topics
RIGHT JOIN courses_names
ON topics.course_id = courses_names.cid
ORDER BY course_id
";
```

my php code is :

```
if($result=mysqli_num_rows($query)!=0)
{

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $topic_name=$row['name'];
        $topics ="<ul>".$topic_name."</ul>";
        $cname  =$row['cname'];
        $course =$cname;
        $output .="<ul>"."<ul>".$course."</ul>".$topics."</ul>";        
    }




}
    else
    {
            $output="No subjects found";
    }

    echo $output;
```

?>
And my output is :
`Maths
trigo
Maths
3d
Maths
algebra
Maths
vectors
Physics
mechanics
Physics
thermodynamics
Chemistry
Avagadro
Computers
C++`

THe problem is repetition of same courses names one , i don't want that rather i want to group all topics of same id in one course id .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Could you show us an example result set which you want to get? How would you like to group the result ?

Comment: I want to do something like this and also want to give link to them, **Maths** : Trigo , algebra , 3d , vectors

**Physics** : mechanics, thermodynamics

**Computers** : c++,java